# Array of arrays not simulating

Tags: vhdl

I am creating a very simplistic SPI slave as part of a larger device and wanted to de-serialize SPI data.  My architecture looks like this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity controller is
       port (
            CLK     : in    std_logic;
            MOSI    : in  std_logic;
            nCS     : in  std_logic;
            SCLK    : in  std_logic;
            OUTPUT_DATA_EN : out   std_logic;
            OUTPUT_DATA : out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
            nRST    : in    std_logic
       );
end controller;

architecture BEH of controller is
     signal SCLK_PREV : std_logic;
     signal nCS_PREV : std_logic;

     type sr8x8 is array(0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

     signal BIT_SHIFT_REG : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     signal BITS_RECEIVED : unsigned(3 downto 0);
     signal SHIFT_REG : sr8x8;
     signal BYTES_RECEIVED : unsigned (7 downto 0);
begin
    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            if nRST = '0' then
                BIT_SHIFT_REG <= (others => '0');
                SHIFT_REG <= (others => (others => '0'));
                BITS_RECEIVED <= (others => '0');
                BYTES_RECEIVED <= (others => '0');
                OUTPUT_DATA <= (others => '0');
                OUTPUT_DATA_EN <= '0';
            else
                if nCS = '1' then
                    BIT_SHIFT_REG <= (others => '0');
                    SHIFT_REG <= (others => (others => '0'));
                    BITS_RECEIVED <= (others => '0');
                    BYTES_RECEIVED <= (others => '0');
                end if;

                if nCS = '0' and SCLK_PREV = '0' and SCLK = '1' then
                    BIT_SHIFT_REG(7 downto 1) <= BIT_SHIFT_REG(6 downto 0);
                    BIT_SHIFT_REG(0) <= MOSI;
                    BITS_RECEIVED <= BITS_RECEIVED + 1;
                end if;

                if nCS = '0' and SCLK_PREV = '1' and SCLK = '0' then
                    if BITS_RECEIVED = 8 then
                        SHIFT_REG(to_integer(BYTES_RECEIVED)) <= BIT_SHIFT_REG;
                        BITS_RECEIVED <= X"0";
                        BYTES_RECEIVED <= BYTES_RECEIVED + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;

                if nCS_PREV = '0' and nCS = '1' then
                    if SHIFT_REG(0) = X"00" then
                        OUTPUT_DATA(31 downto 24) <= SHIFT_REG(1);
                        OUTPUT_DATA(23 downto 16) <= SHIFT_REG(2);
                        OUTPUT_DATA(15 downto 8)  <= SHIFT_REG(3);
                        OUTPUT_DATA(7 downto 0)   <= SHIFT_REG(4);
                        OUTPUT_DATA_EN <= '1';
                    end if;
                end if;

                SCLK_PREV <= SCLK;
                nCS_PREV <= nCS;
            end if;
        end if;
     end process;
end BEH;
```

Everything compiles and synthesizes, but when I go to simulate, everything in the `nRST = '0'` conditional resets, except for `SHIFT_REG`, where all values remain 'U', i.e. all positions of the  8 std_logic_vectors remain 'U'.  This seemed like a reasonable way of building this register based on the syntax documentation I have found.  I have also tried the following methods for resetting `SHIFT_REG` (or any setting at all), and they have no effect:

```
SHIFT_REG <= (others => X"00");
SHIFT_REG(0) <= X"00";
```

Am I doing something invalid for synthesis and/or simulation?  I have some code that evaluates as if the proper values are being stored in `SHIFT_REG`, but the contents never show up in the simulator.

Edit:  If the sensitivity list is reduced to simply `process(CLK)`, the issue remains.

Comment: This may not help, but you can trim down your sensitivity list a lot - all you need in your case is `CLK`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the stuff from your sensitivity list that's not needed - a synchronous reset only requires the clock:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity controller is
end entity;

architecture foo of controller is
   type sr8x8 is array(0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

   signal SHIFT_REG : sr8x8;
   signal BYTES_RECEIVED : unsigned (7 downto 0);
   signal clk:      std_logic := '0';
   signal nRST:     std_logic;


begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if nRST = '0' then
                SHIFT_REG <= (others => (others => '0'));
                BYTES_RECEIVED <= (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 100 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        nRST <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        nRST <= '1';
        wait for 60 ns;
        wait;
    end process;


end architecture;
```

> david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -a controller.vhdl
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -e controller
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -r controller --wave=controller.ghw

gives:

[image: array of arrays reset]

Invocation of processes (and resumptions of processes) are governed by events.  You likely were examining the results of some other event besides a `rising_edge(clk)`.

### After you posted the full controller code

Expanded the test bench to use it:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of tb is

    signal clk:             std_logic := '0';
    signal mosi:            std_logic;
    signal nCS:             std_logic;
    signal sclk:            std_logic;
    signal output_data_en:  std_logic;
    signal output_data:     std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    signal nRST:            std_logic;

    begin

DUT:
    entity work.controller   
    port map (
        clk => clk,
        mosi => mosi,
        nCS => nCS,
        sclk => sclk,
        output_data_en => output_data_en,
        output_data => output_data,
        nRST => nRST
    );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 100 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        nRST <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        nRST <= '1';
        wait for 60 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

    end architecture;
```

Which gives:

[image: full controller reset]

So as we see resetting the array of arrays only requires `CLK` and `nRST`.

For purposes of simulation I don't see anything in your VHDL design description that should prevent you from at least getting `SHIFT_REG` and `BYTES_RECEIVED` reset.

The user documentation and design flow for Altium Designer isn't readily available to third parties, nor is the user documentation for Aldec Active-HDL.  There's little insight to be had from your design description or narrative.

You'd likely be best served by contacting Altium support who would likely set you up with access to Aldec's support services.

Comment: The synthesis tool had generated warnings about not having the other signals listed so I added them.  I had initially just had CLK, since it makes sense to me that the process should only be run on CLK events.  Will try it out as soon as I get back to that computer.

Comment: The synthesis tool should not be generating those warnings unless there's something else wrong in the section of the code you didn't post (or it's not a very good synthesis tool).

Comment: I removed everything from the sensitivity list except `CLK`.  I must have fixed some code along the way, because it's no longer complaining about missing signals in the sensitivity list, however, I'm still getting undefined values in the simulation.  I'm using Altium with the Aldec OEM Simulator.

Comment: It's hard to postulate what's represented by the two "..." regions in your process, but any non-synchronous assignments would be following the two end ifs.  It almost sounds like you have additional drivers somewhere outside the process.  Show more code.

Comment: I've added the full code.  There's some stuff that I don't think will synthesize particularly well, but I think it is all valid, so was trying to work out the simulation issue before I started optimizing.  It seems like the data in `SHIFT_REG` is valid because when `nCS` goes high, `OUTPUT_DATA` is good.

Answer (score 0):

First, depending on your target technology and synthesis tools, an array of arrays might be synthesized to some kind of memory block. You will probably not be able to reset these memories the way you are trying. Check your tool's documentation and your synthesis results.

For the simulator: from the code that you have posted, everything should work. My best guess is that there is another process that drives `SHIFT_REG`. Even if you think you didn't trigger the assignment in that process, it is still driving 'U'. Together with the '0' in this process, that still resolves to 'U'.

Comment: I added the full code.  When `nCS` goes high, the data in `OUTPUT_DATA` appears valid, so `SHIFT_REG` has valid contents at the moment it is transferred to `OUTPUT_DATA`.

Comment: When `nCS` goes high, `OUTPUT_DATA` gets the value that `SHIFT_REG` had on the previous clock tick. Your code looks fine, but it is pretty big now. We have no idea what the input signals are, so there is no way to debug from where we are sitting. Please consider making a VETSMOD example. http://www.sigasi.com/content/vetsmod-get-better-feedback-your-vhdl-code-snippets